# Not logged in to server while login into a server

Tags: android, xmpp, ejabberd, asmack

I am trying to connect with ejabber using BOSH Manager in android with the help of asmack library.

but i am getting following error.

```
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Not logged in to server.
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Roster.reload(Roster.java:197)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.BOSHConnection.login(BOSHConnection.java:351)
    at org.jivesoftware.smack.Connection.login(Connection.java:353)
    at com.bcl.BoradCastLocationActivity$StartXMPPConnection.doInBackground(BoradCastLocationActivity.java:75)
    at com.bcl.BoradCastLocationActivity$StartXMPPConnection.doInBackground(BoradCastLocationActivity.java:1)
    at android.os.AsyncTask$2.call(AsyncTask.java:185)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:306)
    ... 4 more
```

and here is my code

```
SASLAuthentication.registerSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5",SASLDigestMD5Mechanism.class);
SASLAuthentication.supportSASLMechanism("DIGEST-MD5", 1);

System.setProperty("smack.debugEnabled", "true");
XMPPConnection.DEBUG_ENABLED = true;
SmackConfiguration.setPacketReplyTimeout(6000);
BOSHConfiguration bconfig = new
         BOSHConfiguration(false, "example.com", 5280, "/xmpp-http-bind/", "example.com");

bconfig.setSASLAuthenticationEnabled(true);
BOSHConnection xmpp = new BOSHConnection(bconfig);

 xmpp.connect();
 xmpp.login("username","password"); // HERE I AM GETTING AN ERROR
```

Comment: Seems like a bug in aSmack, which was caused by the merge of the BOSH patches and the 3.2.0 branch.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A glance at the aSmack sources indicated that this an an bug. A quick workaround is to to call `Configuration.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false)`, a fix would include moving 3 lines from `BOSHConnection.java:350` after the line `authenticated = true;`.

I have made the changes in aSmack, please run `build.bash` and use the generated .jar.

Comment: i have just added `bconfig.setRosterLoadedAtLogin(false);` and now i am logged in successfully , thanks buddy